# Make use of AppSettings from Web.config in AngulaJS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I guys, I'm converting asp.net c# application to AngularJS but the problem is how I can keep AppSettings from web.config in Angular.

```
<appSettings>
    <!--DEBUG MODE-->
    <add key="AppID" value="pkDesk" />
    <add key="UserID" value="Prashanth" />
    <add key="UploadPath" value="\\pk\AttachmentsUpload\" />
</appSettings>
```

I want it to convert in pure AngularJS, I have found some of Answer on google they have mentioned to use Angular Constant, Angular Services.

How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you mentioned , you can use angular constant in your case

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.constant('AppID', 'pkDesk');
.....
etc
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("constantApp", []);
    app.constant('AppID', "pkDesk");
    app.constant('UserID', "Prashanth");
    app.controller('constantController', function($scope, AppID, UserID) {    
      console.log(UserID);   
      $scope.appID = AppID;
      $scope.userId = UserID;    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Angular JS Services</title>

  <script>
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="constantApp">
  <div ng-controller="constantController">
    <h2>define constant in angularjs</h2>
    <div>URL: {{appID}}</div>
    <div>Title : {{userId}}</div>
    
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: by the way how can we store that Upload Path in constant.

Comment: same way as i mentioned above

Comment: no its showing error.. i have tried, could you edit your example with that value.??

Comment: Unsterminated string constant.

Comment: ok got it i have just removed ending back slash character error was gone. thank you so much Sajeetharan.